# Align axis of separate plots in pgfplots

Tags: pgfplots

I am preparing a talk using plots generated in `pgfplots`' `axis`-environment. I want the plots' axes to be of the exact same size and position. Unfortunately, plots with different axis- and plot-labels differ in size and produce small "jumps" when flipping through the pages of the presentation. In the code below, I illustrate the problem. The axes have the same size, but due to the different labels, their horizontal position shifts. If one comments the `varwidth`option, one can see, that the same thing happens in the vertical direction.

```
\documentclass[crop,10pt,
varwidth=250pt
]{standalone}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.9}
\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
  \begin{axis}[
  width=200pt,
  heigth=200pt,
  xmin=0,xmax=1,ymin=0,ymax=1,
  xlabel=xlabel,
  ylabel=ylabel,
  scale only axis
  ]
  \addplot coordinates{ 
  (0.1,0.1)
  (0.9,0.9)
  };
  \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \begin{axis}[
  width=200pt,
  heigth=200pt,
  xmin=0,xmax=100,ymin=0,ymax=100,
  xlabel=x$_l^a$bel,
  ylabel=y$_l^a$bel,
  scale only axis,
  ]
  \addplot coordinates{ 
  (10,10)
  (90,90)
  };
  \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Is there a way to produce separate plots with axes of exact same size and position?

Comment: you can specify the `width` or `height` of the plots, you'll then probably also want to use `scale only axis=true` to apply this width and height to the rectangle. For more information see the `pgfplots` manual (section 4.10 for `pgfplots` version 1.10).

Comment: You may also need `xmin`, `xmax`, `ymin` and `ymax`. Please add your (minimal working) example to the post. It helps solvers to get into it.

Comment: @hugovdberg @Malipivo I've added the mwe. I always use `width` and `hight` as well as the `x/y min/max` options, the problem comes from the different labels which lead to a different overall size of the graphics and a different position of the axes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks to @hugovdberg I was able to find a solution. One can use the `calc` library to define coordinates relative to the plot's axis and then use `\path[use as bounding box] (first coordinate) rectangle (second coordinate);` to create the bounding box. The following code will produce the desired result. The bounding box is drawn for illustration.

```
\documentclass[10pt]{beamer}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.9}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \begin{axis}[
  width=150pt,
  height=150pt,
  xmin=0,xmax=1,ymin=0,ymax=1,
  xlabel=xlabel,
  ylabel=ylabel,
  scale only axis,
  ]
  \addplot coordinates{ 
  (0.1,0.1)
  (0.9,0.9)
  };
  \end{axis}
  \coordinate (topleft) at ($(current axis.north west) + (-1.3cm,0.3cm)$);
  \coordinate (bottomright) at ($(current axis.south east) + (0.4cm,-1cm)$);
  \path[use as bounding box,draw] (topleft) rectangle (bottomright);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{frame}
\begin{frame}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \begin{axis}[
  width=150pt,
  height=150pt,
  xmin=0,xmax=100,ymin=0,ymax=100,
  xlabel=x$_l^a$bel,
  ylabel=y$_l^a$bel,
  scale only axis,
  ]
  \addplot coordinates{ 
  (10,10)
  (90,90)
  };
  \end{axis}
  \coordinate (topleft) at ($(current axis.north west) + (-1.3cm,0.3cm)$);
  \coordinate (bottomright) at ($(current axis.south east) + (0.4cm,-1cm)$);
  \path[use as bounding box,draw] (topleft) rectangle (bottomright);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Comment: I think you should not have to specify the `overlay` style for the labels since you specify the entire boundingbox by hand. Removing it will probably not increase efficiency but definitely increases legibilty of the code by keeping it as clean as possible. Also specifying the same bounding everytime is bound to get messed up if you have to correct it everywhere. I would put the `\coordinate` and `\path` commands in a new macro so you only have to change it in a single position.

Answer (score 3):

I think section *4.20
The Picture’s Size: Bounding Box and Clipping* of the `pgfplots` manual (v1.10) might be of use, you can use the `overlay` style specification to exclude parts from the bounding box, thus aligning only the axes themselves, regardless of the size of the labels.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.9}
\begin{document}
\begin{center}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \begin{axis}[
    width=200pt,
    height=200pt,
    xmin=0,xmax=1,ymin=0,ymax=1,
    xlabel=xlabel,
    ylabel=ylabel,
    ylabel style={overlay},
    yticklabel style={overlay},
    xlabel style={overlay},
    xticklabel style={overlay},
    scale only axis
    ]
    \addplot coordinates{
      (0.1,0.1)
        (0.9,0.9)
    };
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{center}
\vspace*{4em}
\begin{center}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
  width=200pt,
  height=200pt,
  xmin=0,xmax=100,ymin=0,ymax=100,
  xlabel=x$_l^a$bel,
  ylabel=y$_l^a$bel,
  ylabel style={overlay},
  yticklabel style={overlay},
  xlabel style={overlay},
  xticklabel style={overlay},
  scale only axis,
  ]
  \addplot coordinates{
    (10,10)
      (90,90)
  };
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{center}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. This does work when using the `article` class. But I usually use `standalone` with the `crop` option to create the figure. Here, the `center` environment has no effect, as the picture is cropped at the bounding box. The `overlay` style also makes it difficult to scale the whole picture to a certain width. The best approach would propably be to define a fixed distance between the axes and the bounding box, but I don't see how...

Comment: Did you take a look at the section I refer to in the `pgfplots` manual? There are some more settings, including sepecification of a custom shape as bounding box. I don't have time to look into the finer details now, but keeping the axis `width` & `height` fixed, with `scale only axis` and setting a new bounding box a fixed distance (in cm?) relative to the `current axis` might do the trick.

Comment: Thanks to your suggestions, I was able to produce a solution. Is there any way I can share the reputation except upvoting your answer?